# Internal server Error when physical memory is exhausted

Tags: cpanel

What causes physical memory, entry process resource allocation to be exhausted and display internal server error and what is the best solution to fix the error ?

Answer (score 0):

For fix the high amount of Entry Process, you must completely analyze the scripts and applications running inside your websites to findout which one is taking too much resource.